# LineBackgroundSpan drawBackground is not called

Tags: android, spannable, android-spannable

I have a custom span, its superclass is `LineBackgroundSpan`.

```
class CustomUnderlineSpan(
    private val underlineDrawable: Drawable
) : LineBackgroundSpan {

    override fun drawBackground(
        canvas: Canvas,
        paint: Paint,
        left: Int,
        right: Int,
        top: Int,
        baseline: Int,
        bottom: Int,
        text: CharSequence,
        start: Int,
        end: Int,
        lineNumber: Int
    ) {
        // For some devices this method is not always called
        underlineDrawable.draw(canvas)
    }

}
```

I'm creating span like this:

```
    SpannableString(fullText).apply {
        setSpan(
            CustomUnderlineSpan(bodyState.drawable),
            fullText.indexOf(phrase),
            fullText.indexOf(phrase) + phrase.length,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        )
    }
```

For some devices the `drawBackground` method of some spans is not called.

What could be the reason?